# Passing data from JSON config array via dependency injection not working in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

Using ASP.Net Core 2, I'm unable to pass configuration data stored in a JSON array via DI. In ASP.NET Core 1.1, my approach is working flawlessly. I already read the MS documentation concerning DI and options in version 2, but nothing seems to have changed.

While debugging the application with Visual Studio, I can confirm that the `Configuration` object contains the data from the `JsonConfigurationProvider`. But somehow the binding fails and the injected `IOptionsSnapshot.Value.FaqDataList` instance is always null.

What am I missing? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

faq.json:

```
{
 "faqData": [
   {
    "Question": "Title1",
    "Answer": "Text1"
   },
   ...more items
 ]
}
```

Program.cs:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
            config.AddJsonFile("faq.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .Build();
```

POCO-Classes:

```
public class FaqData {
    public List<FaqDataItem> FaqDataList { get; set; }
}

public class FaqDataItem {
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.Configure<FaqData>(Configuration);
        // Doesn't work either:
        // services.Configure<FaqData>(Configuration.GetSection("faqData"));
        services.AddMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid:

```
"faqData": {
"FaqDataList": [
  {
    "Question": "Title1",
    "Answer": "Text1"
  }
]
```

}

You are having a property FaqDataList which is a list of FaqDataItem.

And I am not really aware is it possible to go with

```
services.Configure<FaqData>(Configuration);
```

but the

```
services.Configure<FaqData>(Configuration.GetSection("faqData"));
```

should work

Comment: Thank you, Gvozden. The invalid JSON was the culprit. It's working now as expected. :]